# When and why is better to use string format in printing log?

Tags: java, printing, log4j, string-formatting

I want to print in my log application, using log4j, some value (String, date, ecc).
For example:

```
Sting idUser="Test123";
String name="Jack";
int age=22;

applicationlog.info("The selected user has this value :\n");
applicationlog.info("name :"+name+ "id: "+idUser+" age :"+age);
```

But I have sow that in some application there is written:

```
applicationlog.info(String.format("name :%s id :%s age :%d",name,idUser,age));
```

So my question is :
When and why is better to use String format instead of "+" only in the print log? I known that with string with concatenation is better to use "+", but I don't thing this is the case, infact here there are only print. 
Thank you

Comment: It's easier for you to write

Comment: what? string format ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference in performance.

```
applicationlog.info("name :"+name+ "id: "+idUser+" age :"+age);
```

In your specific case you would not notice because you are using `String`s but if the objects you want to log are more complex but contain a `toString` method then in this case the `toString` method will **always** be called, whatever the log level.

```
applicationlog.info(String.format("name :%s id :%s age :%d",name,idUser,age));
```

In this case, if logging is switched off for example, then the `toString` methods of the objects will **not** be called.

This applies more to `DEBUG` or `TRACE` level logging but it is a worthwhile habit to get into.

Many loggers will also provide parameter substitution mechanisms which can be a better approach which also implements this feature.

```
applicationlog.info("name: {} id: {} age: {}", name, idUser, age);
```

Comment: so, you suggest me to use string format when I want to print a string value of an objects, because is more performing? Is a best pratise or not? There not a real best pratise on using string format or not, right?

Comment: @LizLamperouge - I make no suggestions. I point out that there is a *potential* performance hit to using string concatenation. **You** decide whether that cost is worthwhile when it is clearly easier to concatenate when writing your code. Personally I prefer parameter substitution but it is your call.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to seem controversial, It's only a doubt that I have and I want to understand the reason why =) thank you for your time and help =)

Comment: @LizLamperouge You should never apologise for being inquisitive. :)

Answer (score 1):

log4j v2 has built in support for [Substituting Parameters](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html)

```
applicationlog.info("name: {} id: {} age: {}", name, idUser, age);
```

as well as `printf` which supports... printf style

```
applicationlog.printf("name: %s id: %s age: %d", name, idUser, age);
```

Comment: Really wish this were in the default `java.util.logging` library

Comment: @ifly6 `JUL` is bad in so many ways that if you're using it you can only blame yourself.

Comment: @Sharon ok but, what is the improvement to use Substituting Parameters instead of String format or "+" ?